# From jersey rest application, I can't get the right URL

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm new with Jersey Rest Framework and I wrote an simple demo to learn this skill. Here is my problem: I tried to reach my helloworld with this URL---

```
http://localhost:8080/PayInterface/query/helloworld
```

but didn't work. Would you please tell me what I did wrong?
I wrote a class:

```
@Component
//Declaring that all it will handle all requests starting by /TestCaseDto
@Path("query")
public class QueryApi {
    @Path("/helloworld")
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String test(){
        return new String("Hello World!!!");
    }
}
```

and I

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Where/how is it deployed? How are you making the request? What happens when you do? What diagnostics have you employed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in here you return string. so you can't give produce type as **xml**,Try this

```
@Stateless
@Path("query")
public class QueryApi {
   @Path("/helloworld")
   @GET
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public String test(){
     return new String("Hello World!!!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more detail about this "dint work" would be nice 
for starters- try changing your path above your class name like this

```
@Path("/query")
```